# Reading YAML from ruby is printing incorrect values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a YAML file with the following structure:

```
mytext:
  mykey: "\x9A\xA6@\e8ddw\xB6&*\xFFr\x81\\\xC8@\xCC\x1E^\xD6\x13^\xD2\x91\x17\xEA\xB0\x001\xDD\xC1"
  myvalue: "8\xD8I\x00=\x9E\xF2I\x99tUK\xFD\x16\xA3Y"
```

I use the below ruby code to read data from this YAML file:

```
yamlfilen = YAML::load_file('yamlfile.yml') #Load
mykey = yamlfilen['mytext']['mykey'] 
myiv = yamlfilen['mytext']['myvalue'] 

p mykey
p myiv
```

When I see the value printed in the console i see this:

```
"\\x9A\\xA6@\\e8ddw\\xB6&*\\xFFr\\x81\\\\\\xC8@\\xCC\\x1E^\\xD6\\x13^\\xD2\\x91\\x17\\xEA\\xB0\\x001\\xDD\\xC1"
"8\\xD8I\\x00=\\x9E\\xF2I\\x99tUK\\xFD\\x16\\xA3Y"
```

> Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Its escaping the `\\`

Comment: try to set the value in yaml file without quotes

Comment: I’m not getting those results, I get the unescaped data. What version of Ruby (and Yaml) are you using? You might be better of using explicitly binary strings for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out It's not giving you incorrect values

```
"8\\xD8I\\x00=\\x9E\\xF2I\\x99tUK\\xFD\\x16\\xA3Y"
```

This is actually the correct value but the `\` are escaped with additional `\`.

That's why when you see a string it will show you `\` twice

If you just print the value you will see the correct value

```
puts "8\\xD8I\\x00=\\x9E\\xF2I\\x99tUK\\xFD\\x16\\xA3Y"

#=> 8\xD8I\x00=\x9E\xF2I\x99tUK\xFD\x16\xA3Y
```

**NOTE:** `\` is escape character used for special characters for ex.

- **`\t`** -> Tab
- **`\n`** -> New Line